# How to get Count of rows in java from table of Access JDBC ODBC database

Tags: java, netbeans, ms-access-2003

Hi i am developing a system in java i am trying to get the count of all records present in my table i tried a lot but it is  giving me exception 
Exception is:
 - java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support this function

here is my code below.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
public class myfram2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;//I have also tried Statement but it give me exception that:
                     //Column not found     
public myfram2() {
   try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con= con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Connection succeed");
    }catch(Exception ex){

    ex.printStackTrace();

    }

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
ResultSet rsc;
    try{
   //Here i am using sql count method and also tried max but it doesn't work
    String sqcount="Select count(stdid)from record";

  ps=con.prepareStatement(sqcount);

  rsc=ps.executeQuery(sqcount);
  if(rsc.next()){

  String getc= rsc.getString("count(stdid)");
  searchtx.setText(getc);

  }

    }
  catch(Exception ex){

  ex.printStackTrace();

  }


  }
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: on count method, the query is correct  but the driver is not supporting the count max or sum method ,is there any other driver available for access database connection

Answer (score 2):

Either you have to use for your current code :

```
 String getc = rsc.getString(1);
```

or change:

```
  String sqcount = "Select count(stdid) countStdID from record";
```

and then:

```
String getc = rsc.getString("countStdID");
```

**Edit: 1**

You must load the `Driver Class` first then get connection from that driver class, and that connection in your program.

**Edit 2:**

You must use

```
rsc = ps.executeQuery();    // instead of rsc = ps.executeQuery(sqcount);
```

because `PreparedStatement` is a precompiled set of query

Comment: Is there any other driver available for access database connection? ,because i am getting error that driver not support this method

Comment: @AbdullahSyed which driver you are using currently? i dont see code for loading driver class in your question.

Comment: Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con= con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student");

Comment: @AbdullahSyed please see `Edit2` in my answer,i think there is no problem of driver, and let me know if this works or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way,

```
Select count(stdid) c from record

String getc = rsc.getString("c");
```